# C Sharp form constant updating?

Tags: c#, forms, methods, action

Through Visual Studio you can easily create a method for an event (button click, etc). Is there a way to create a method for multiple events, like a method that would run any time one of three buttons were clicked, or one of many textboxes were typed in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've created the method once you should be able to use it for any other event that has a similar signature.

From the Designer, don't double-click the method but instead drop down the list for any existing event handler that *can* be assigned to your chosen event.

Like @lcfseth notes, you can identify which particular control sent the message via the `object sender` argument.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add that the "sender" parameter identify which control raised the event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,you can bind many events to the same method (events of the same signature)

```
firstEvent += MyMethod;
secondEvent += MyMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a function to an object's event you're actually passing a delegate (i.e. a pointer-to-function) to its event handler. You can bind the same function to as many objects' event handlers as you want, as long as the required delegate's signature corresponds.

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.AnyButton_Click);
Button2.Click += new EventHandler(this.AnyButton_Click);
Button3.Click += new EventHandler(this.AnyButton_Click);
```

In case you need to run specific operations on the "sender" object depending on which button was clicked pay attention that the function's argument "sender" is the button you clicked so if you need to work on the button object remember to unbox it to its specific class (i.e. cast it to Button or whatever its type is).

```
void AnyButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender; // unbox the sender
    MessageBox.Show("You just clicked button " clickedButton.Text);
}
```

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the same handler to Click events of multiple controls.  sender points to the control that caused the event.